# Laravel Restful Controller ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

So to explain my issue, whenever i am connecting to the database with Laravel it will default search for the id column as "id".

[image]

If i name my column jobID for example, i would like to controller to search for "jobID" instead of just "id". I could just change all of my tables ID columns to "id" however this causes issues when you use Laravel's left joins as it will take the latest id column as the actual id column.

Heres my join:

```
   $jobs = Job::leftJoin('occupational_areas', function($join) {
             $join->on('jobs.occupationalArea', '=', 'occupational_areas.id');
           })->get();
```

However Restful controller default to "id" and that is what i'm asking, how do i change the default "id" to becomes something more custom like jobID

Comment: what's your id field named in your `jobs`table??

Answer (score 1):

Try using this left join

```
 $jobs = Job::select('occupational_areas.id as occ_id', 'jobs.id as jobs_id', your required values)
        ->leftJoin('occupational_areas', 'jobs.occupationalArea', '=', 'occupational_areas.id')
        ->get();
```

comment for errors

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same error. Basically ocupational_areas.id is overwriting job.id, ideally i would like to call it job.jobID to get passed this, however laravels restful controllers only want to search my tables for "id".

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the easiest way to do this is by setting:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'jobID';
```

Into your model.

I am pretty sure Ronser also had it right with his method. Either will work.

Thanks Ronser!